# Speech recognition with Microsoft Cognitive Speech API and non-microphone real-time audio stream

Tags: c#, audio, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services, cscore

### Problem

My project consists of a desktop application that records audio in real-time, for which I intend to receive real-time recognition feedback from an API. With a **microphone**, a real-time implementation using Microsoft's new Speech-to-Text API is trivial, with my scenario differing from that only in the sense that my data is written to a `MemoryStream` object.

### API Support

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-use-audio-input-streams) explains how to implement the API's `Recognizer` ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.recognizer)) with **custom audio streams**, which invariably requires the implementation of the abstract class `PullAudioInputStream` ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.audio.pullaudioinputstream)) in order to create the required `AudioConfig` object using the `CreatePullStream` method ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.audio.audioinputstream.createpullstream)). In other words, to achieve what I require, a callback interface must be implemented.

### Implementation attempt

Since my data is written to a MemoryStream (and the library I use will only record to files or Stream objects), in the code below I simply copy over the buffer to the implemented class (*in a sloppy way, perhaps?*) resolving the divergence in method signatures.

```
class AudioInputCallback : PullAudioInputStreamCallback
{
    private readonly MemoryStream memoryStream;

    public AudioInputCallback(MemoryStream stream)
    {
        this.memoryStream = stream;
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] dataBuffer, uint size)
    {
        return this.Read(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
    }

    private int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        return memoryStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    public override void Close()
    {
        memoryStream.Close();
        base.Close();
    }

}
```

The `Recognizer` implementation is as follows:

```
private SpeechRecognizer CreateMicrosoftSpeechRecognizer(MemoryStream memoryStream)
{
    var recognizerConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(SubscriptionKey, @"westus");
    recognizerConfig.SpeechRecognitionLanguage =
        _programInfo.CurrentSourceCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;

    // Constants are used as constructor params)
    var format = AudioStreamFormat.GetWaveFormatPCM(
        samplesPerSecond: SampleRate, bitsPerSample: BitsPerSample, channels: Channels);

    // Implementation of PullAudioInputStreamCallback
    var callback = new AudioInputCallback(memoryStream);
    AudioConfig audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromStreamInput(callback, format);

    //Actual recognizer is created with the required objects
    SpeechRecognizer recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(recognizerConfig, audioConfig);

    // Event subscriptions. Most handlers are implemented for debugging purposes only.
    // A log window outputs the feedback from the event handlers.
    recognizer.Recognized += MsRecognizer_Recognized;
    recognizer.Recognizing += MsRecognizer_Recognizing;
    recognizer.Canceled += MsRecognizer_Canceled;
    recognizer.SpeechStartDetected += MsRecognizer_SpeechStartDetected;
    recognizer.SpeechEndDetected += MsRecognizer_SpeechEndDetected;
    recognizer.SessionStopped += MsRecognizer_SessionStopped;
    recognizer.SessionStarted += MsRecognizer_SessionStarted;

    return recognizer;
}
```

How the data is made available to the recognizer (using CSCore):

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(_finalSource.WaveFormat.BytesPerSecond / 2);
byte[] buffer = new byte[_finalSource.WaveFormat.BytesPerSecond / 2];

_soundInSource.DataAvailable += (s, e) =>
{
    int read;
    _programInfo.IsDataAvailable = true;

    // Writes to MemoryStream as event fires
    while ((read = _finalSource.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
};

// Creates MS recognizer from MemoryStream
_msRecognizer = CreateMicrosoftSpeechRecognizer(memoryStream);

//Initializes loopback capture instance
_soundIn.Start();

await Task.Delay(1000);

// Starts recognition
await _msRecognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync();
```

### Outcome

When the application is run, I don't get any exceptions, nor any response from the API other than `SessionStarted` and `SessionStopped`, as depicted below in the log window of my application.

[image]

I could use suggestions of different approaches to my implementation, as I suspect there is some timing problem in tying the recorded `DataAvailable` event with the actual sending of data to the API, which is making it discard the session prematurely. With no detailed feedback on why my requests are unsuccessful, I can only guess at the reason.

Comment: Hi @Renato, did you resolve this ? please share the solutions if you found, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The `Read()` callback of `PullAudioInputStream` should block if there is no data immediate available. And `Read()` returns 0, only if the stream reaches the end. The SDK will then close the stream after `Read()` returns 0 (find an API reference doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.audio.pullaudioinputstreamcallback.read?view=azure-dotnet#returns)).

However, the behavior of Read() of C# MemoryStream is different: It returns 0 if there is no data available in the buffer. This is why you only see `SessionStart` and `SessionStop` events, but no recognition events.

In order to fix that, you need to add some kind of synchronization between `PullAudioInputStream::Read()` and `MemoryStream::Write()`, in order to make sure that `PullAudioInputStream::Read()` will wait until `MemoryStream::Write()` writes some data into buffer.

Alternatively, I would recommend to use `PushAudioInputStream`, which allows you directly write your data into stream. For your case, in `_soundSource.DataAvailable` event, instead of writing data into `MemoryStream`, you can directly write it into `PushAudioInputStream`. You can find samples for `PushAudioInputStream` [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/csharp/sharedcontent/console/speech_recognition_samples.cs#L309).

We will update the documentation in order to provide the best practice on how to use Pull and Push `AudioInputStream`. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Thank you!

Comment: Do we have the recommendation page about when to use push/pullaudioinputstream

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was able to solve this problem using NAudio.

Here Is the code that starts the audio stream recording:

```
computerAudioWriter = new WaveFileWriter(new MemoryStream(),computerAudioCapture.WaveFormat);
computerAudioStream = new NAudioStream();


// Start recording
computerAudioCapture.StartRecording();
computerAudioCapture.DataAvailable += async (sender, e) =>
{
  if (e.BytesRecorded > 0)
  {
    // Write data to computer audio
    computerAudioStream.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
  }
};
```

This is the class that can be used with PullAudioInputStreamCallback.

```
public class NAudioStream : PullAudioInputStreamCallback
{
    private MemoryStream memoryStream;
    private ManualResetEvent newData;

    public NAudioStream()
    {
        
        this.memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        this.newData = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    }

    public void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        // Write data to the memory stream and set the reset event
         memoryStream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
         newData.Set();

    }

    public void Close()
    {
        newData.Set();
    }

    private int bytesCounter = 0;

    public override int Read(byte[] dataBuffer, uint size)
    {

        if (memoryStream == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        int bytesRead = 0;

        while (bytesRead < size)
        {
            newData.WaitOne(); // Block until there are bytes to read

            byte[] wavBuffer = memoryStream.ToArray();
            int bytesToRead = (int)(size - bytesRead);

            if (bytesToRead > wavBuffer.Length - bytesCounter)
            {
                bytesToRead = wavBuffer.Length - bytesCounter;
            }

            if (bytesToRead > 0)
            {
                Array.Copy(wavBuffer, bytesCounter, dataBuffer, bytesRead, bytesToRead);
                bytesRead += bytesToRead;
                bytesCounter += bytesToRead;
            }
            newData.Reset();
            return (int)bytesRead;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Full implementation can be found here: https://github.com/Mallock/sam-smart-agent-manager/blob/main/sam/NAudioStream.cs